# C#_How to insert a string into each columns table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, string

How to insert a string into each columns table SQL
Example, I have a string :

> /Hanoi/a2.3b6.7c8.4/Tphcm/n7.2a5.2

I tried many ways, however I got this result:

[image]

I don't know anyway to insert it into a table, I want they look like:

[image]

Can you suggest any ideal for me, please?

Comment: As you see, your string has a scheme. Try to get this scheme and write a code

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is your problem splitting the string? How must it be splitted? Or your problem is inserting the records in the database? As is, this question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my way how to do if i need to develop it.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();

        string foo = "/Hanoi/a2.3b6.7c8.4/Tphcm/n7.2a5.2";

        var bo = foo.Remove(0, 1).Split('/'); // split data by '/'

        // even bo elenment is address and odd element has specific data like number and letter
        for (int i = 0; i < bo.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            var str = bo[i]; // Address
            var str1 = bo[i + 1]; // Letter and Number

            var arrLetters = str1.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray(); // Get Letters

            for (int j = 0; j < arrLetters.Length; j++)
            {
                string splittedLetter = string.Empty; 
                string number = string.Empty;

                if (j+1 != arrLetters.Length)
                {
                    splittedLetter = str1.Split(arrLetters[j + 1])[0]; 
                    number = Regex.Replace(splittedLetter, "[A-Za-z ]", "");
                    str1 = str1.Replace(splittedLetter, string.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    number = Regex.Replace(str1, "[A-Za-z ]", "");
                }

                // add to list, db or where you want :)
                locations.Add(new Location
                {
                    Address = str,
                    Letter = arrLetters[j].ToString(),
                    Number = number
                });
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Location
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Letter { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

List members data like your db result.
[image]

I hope this solution help to you

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the required information from the input string mentioned /Hanoi/a2.3b6.7c8.4/Tphcm/n7.2a5.2 by the parameter "/"

   a. split complete string in to an array
    string str = "/Hanoi/a2.3b6.7c8.4/Tphcm/n7.2a5.2";
    string[] words = str.Split('/');

   b. Extract required data from the words array
2. Write a sql query/LINQ to insert each string/numbers in to the related columns

Let us know if you see any issues in implementing this.

Comment: I want to add string directly table because my real string so long. I don't insert value manually like:
INSERT dbo.Getinfomation1
        ( Adress, Letter, Number )
VALUES  ( N'Tphcm',
          N'n',
          7.2

Comment: The big problem is DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO your step 2

Comment: you are able to extract required values from the main string? You want LINQ statement to insert the values right?

Comment: Yes.Can i use BULK INSERT ? I have searched it on GG